# What are the circumstances under which onBindViewHolder() in RecyclerView.Adapter is not called?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented my own adapter for a `RecyclerView` with subheaders. The problem is, that sometimes the header views are not bind to new values from the dataset because `onBindViewHolder(...)` method is not called. I traced this behavior via logcat: it literally misses the positions for some of the headers. Why is that?

Comment: When you return zero items.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without any code. You should provide your adapter's implementation. And answer to your question : I'ts not called if the item is visible on the screen and notifyDataSetChanged not called.

Comment: I have checked number of items in the dataset that I return - no mistakes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug in my code! `getItemId()` was not returning unique ids for the headers. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the method `getItemCount()` doesn't return 0 as this could possibly result in `onBindViewHolder()` not being called.

Comment: My subheaders and actual items are objects of the same type. I put them all into one dataset array and  make binding decisions on the basis of what values they have.

`getItemCount()` simpply returns `dataset.getSize()`. `Dataset` is always NOT empty.